# mapleader & <Nop>: strange timeout behavior

Tags: key-bindings

I use **`<Space>`** as my leader key, with a short `timeoutlen`:

```
let mapleader = ' '
set timeout timeoutlen=300 ttimeoutlen=5
```

Sometimes in normal mode, I hit **`<Space>`** then hesitate (maybe I changed my mind), letting the timeout expire as I consider my next move.

Normally this would trigger the default **`<Space>`** behavior, moving cursor to the right. To prevent this, I've added:

```
nnoremap <Space> <Nop>
```

The problem with this is, after the timeout has expired, I can't reinitiate a leader key-sequence until I run some (any) other command, such as hitting `Esc`. It's as if I need to break out of the `<Nop>` with some intervening command.

For example, with `nnoremap <leader>j <Plug>(foo)`,

- I type **`<Space>`** and let the timeout expire
- then I type **`<Space>j`** expecting it to run `<Plug>(foo)`, but it does nothing
- I hit `Esc`
- I type **`<Space>j`** --> Vim runs `<Plug>(foo)`

If I change my mapleader to **`\`** and do `map <Space> \`, I don't have this problem.

What's causing this timeout/Nop behavior? Is there a way to fix it, or should I use the **`\`** workaround?

***Update***

This appears to be a known (recent?) bug.

- https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/6419
- https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1548
- https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6241

Comment: There's now an answer to this question here: [Using a no-op key in insert mode, can't use key after using no-op mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13862/using-a-no-op-key-in-insert-mode-cant-use-key-after-using-no-op-mapping)