# Is <c-g><c-g> equivalent to <nop> in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings

I've tried `:help i_CTRL-G_CTRL-G` and `:helpgrep CTRL-G` more generally and can't figure out why `<c-g><c-g>` is equivalent to a `<nop>` in insert mode.

For some context, I was having problems with the mapping:

```
nnoremap ` <nop>
```

And it was suggested in a comment here: [Using a no-op key in insert mode, can't use key after using no-op mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13862/using-a-no-op-key-in-insert-mode-cant-use-key-after-using-no-op-mapping)
That I should use

```
nnoremap ` <c-g><c-g>
```

instead.

Using this workaround the problem is avoided, but I can't figure out why it works. In particular, I'm trying to understand how `<c-g><c-g>` duplicates some or perhaps all of the observable behavior of `<nop>` ... while simultaneously hitting a different enough codepath to avoid triggering the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you saw in your search `:help i_CTRL-G_CTRL-G` doesn't exist. It simply means that by default it is mapped to nothing thus pressing <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd><kbd>CTRL-G</kbd> will do nothing which is equivalent to `<nop>`.

In their comment @Mass said it is a workaround: you are abusing the fact that <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd><kbd>CTRL-G</kbd> does nothing to replicate the behavior of `<nop>` without sending the `<nop>` keycode. You could get the equivalent with basically any nonexisting mapping like `<c-g><c-a>`, `<c-g><c-b>`, etc